# How can I create 3 way data structure for ragged data?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have ragged data where there are different classes within different schools within different cities.

```r
city <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)

school <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,
8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)

x1 <- c(23,43,12,23,34,43,23,23,12,23,34,17,36,26,25,28,33,33,33,13,25,25,
35,34,23,19,18,27,33,28,23,23,12,23,34,17,36,23,34,17,36,26,25)

x2 <- c(33,13,25,25,35,34,23,19,18,27,23,43,12,23,34,43,23,23,12,23,33,33,
28,23,23,12,23,34,17,36,23,34,17,36,26,25,34,17,36,26,25,28,33)

x3 <- c(22,18,25,23,22,33,23,22,18,22,28,38,26,18,19,28,27,23,26,24,37,28,
28,22,24,17,24,32,16,38,25,33,19,31,25,24,32,18,33,23,22,25,36)

data<- data.frame(city,school,x1,x2,x3)
```

I wanna create 3-way data structures and use for loop to access each class's values (x1-x3)?

(note: I am not looking for list within list `[[]]` since I cannot use it with `r-jags`).

How can I specify the different number of classes and schools? one suggestion is using the max number within of classes within each school!

```r
for (i in length(unique(city))) {  # number of cities
  for (j in ... ) { # number of school in each city
    for (k in ... )  # number of classes in each school
      y[k,j,i] <- mean + beta1*x1[k,j,i] + beta2*x2[k,j,i]
  }
}
```

Note, my provided data is a subset of huge data. I wanna use for loop to extract out each single value (ex; x1[1,1,1] = 23 ). 
Also, Is there a way to specify all different dimensions for schools and classes?

Comment: Can you explain more about your ultimate goal? There might be more idiomatic ways to structure this in R than a nested loop.

Comment: I just wanna use a nested loop since I can use it with rjags. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want. The data data frame can be converted to a 3-dimensional array.

```
X <- array(NA, dim=c(3, 10, 3), dimnames=list(city=1:3, school=1:10,
     classes=c("X1", "X2", "X3")))
X[,,1] <- xtabs(x1~city + school, data)
X[,,2] <- xtabs(x2~city + school, data)
X[,,3] <- xtabs(x3~city + school, data)
str(X)
#  num [1:3, 1:10, 1:3] 178 0 0 58 0 0 74 0 0 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#   ..$ city   : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
#   ..$ school : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   ..$ classes: chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
ftable(X, row.vars=c(1, 3), col.vars=2)
#              school   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
# city classes                                               
# 1    X1             178  58  74   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#      X2             165  60  93   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#      X3             143  63  88   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2    X1               0   0   0 115  99  38 136 106   0   0
#      X2               0   0   0 112  58  56 119 110   0   0
#      X3               0   0   0  91  76  61 119 110   0   0
# 3    X1               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 132 197
#      X2               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 161 199
#      X3               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 157 189
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my current data is a subset of huge data is there a way to specify all different dimensions for schools and classes?
also, I wanna extract all single values (ex, x1[1,1,1]=23)

Comment: You can add as many dimensions as you want subject to your computer's memory. I assumed that the values in X1, X2, X3 were counts. Are they something else? I don't think your proposed method can work. What are the three dimensions of the x1 array? I see city and school, but no third dimension since x is not a dimension according to your approach. What would x1[1, 1, 2] be? In your approach, most of the index values would be empty. Wouldn't it just be easier to just use `data[1, "x1"]` to get the 23 value?

Comment: 3-dim are city, school, and each row within each school is representing a class (ex, first city has three schools and each school has different number of classes, first school has 6 classes ). the values x1, x2, x3 are not counts. Ex, each value of x1 represents number of boys in different classes. why I wanna for loop cause i wanna run a model as my previous model and;   `mean[i,j] = gamma*x3[i,j]`

Comment: The number of boys is a count. You have 2-dimensional data and x3 is a vector (1-dimensional).

Comment: you summed all values of x1 by schools which not acceptable in my case. And I can't use `data[1,"x1"]` because my model is dealing separately within city then school then class. (ex, with i=1 first city thin j=1,...,J different schools then k=1,....,K diferent classes within each school). so, they must be within nested loop.